# Dynamically hide/show arrow button on input element of type number with Lit

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit

How to dynamically show/hide arrow buttons on `<input type="number">` with `Lit`?

Here is a solution on how to do this task statically (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp):

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

I need to use a property and depending on its value either display or hide the arrow buttons. The following approach doesn't work in combination with a class:

```js
@property({ type: Boolean }) hideNumberArrows = false
```

```html
<input
  class="${this.hideNumberArrows ? 'my-class-name' : ''}"
/>
```

```css
input.my-class-name::-webkit-outer-spin-button
input.my-class-name::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to work when I pass to my component like this `. hideNumberArrows="${true}"`. For other boolean properties, where the css class is set the same way it also works like this `propname="true"`